# Create 2 parallel string arrays from text file using getline

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, file-io, istream

For this task, I am opening a text file and trying to read lines 1 and 3 into the array named front (at indices 0 and 1 respectively), and then read lines 2 and 4 into the array named back (at indices 0 and 1 respectively), but it's not quite doing it. Nothing is getting inputted into the arrays, my loop logic must be off. I want to read each line as is (with spaces included) up until the newline character. Any help is appreciated.

```
void initialize(string front[], string back[], ifstream &inFile)
{
    string fileName = "DevDeck.txt";    //Filename
    string line;
    inFile.open(fileName); //Open filename

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Couldn't open the file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //Create the parallel arrays
    while (!inFile.eof())   
    {       
        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        {       
            getline(inFile, line); 
            front[index] = line; //Store in first array

            getline(inFile, line); 
            back[index] = line; //Store in second array
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop `for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)` has the wrong condition since you want 4 strings in total but in each loop you get 2 so right now you would get 8 strings.

I tried to run your code with that change like this:

```
int main()
{
    string front[2];
    string back[2];

    ifstream inFile;

    initialize(front, back, inFile);

    cout << front[0] << endl << back[0] << endl << front[1] << endl << back[1];

    return 0;
}
```

and it worked perfectly for me. It displayed:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

In order to help you further you should provide the `DevDeck.txt` file and the piece of code that calls this function.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the array sizes were off.

`//Global constant`
`const int NUMCARDS = 2;`

`/inside main`
`string front[NUMCARDS];`
`string back[NUMCARDS];`
`ifstream infile;`


Works great now. Ty.